# Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive default-src ,so default-src is used as a fallback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean

I am creating a web app using the mean stack in angular 6 but I am getting below  error message on the browser console.

> "Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that
>   'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback."

Code:

```
 getUsers() {
    return this._http.get("/api/users")
      .pipe(map(result => this.result = result.json().data));
  }
```

Comment: [Content security policy](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/CSP). not sure how angular has something to do with it. this is a new standard for modern browsers (read the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/))

Answer (score 10):

Content security policy is a way for modern browsers, to define a set of restrictions when loading remote resources.

Response headers from the HTTP protocol can set those policies:

> `Content-Security-Policy` header (official), `X-Content-Security-Policy` (supported by Mozilla Firefox and IE10) and `X-WebKit-CSP` (supported by Google Chrome and Safari) HTTP response headers with the list of Content Security Policy directives. *(from [seckit drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/seckit))*

You can set different policies to different types of elements in the DOM (e.g `<img>`, `<script>`, `<object>`, `<embed>`, `<iframe>` and so on...), to restrict requests that originates from that element.

[image: Screenshot of request with policy]

So you need to change `'self'` to one of the following:

- `'none'` - block content from any source
- `'self'` - allow content only from your domain
- `'unsafe-inline'` - allow specific inline content (note, that it is supported by a subset of directives)
- `'unsafe-eval'` - allow a set of string-to-code API which is restricted by default (supported by script-src directive)

Wildcards (*) are allowed:

- `*` - load content from any source
- `*.example.com` - load content from example.com and all its subdomains
- `example.com:*` - load content from example.com via any port.  -
- Otherwise, it will use your website default port

Answer (score 9):

Adding 'self' and data: to the font-src works for me.

```
Content-Security-Policy: font-src 'self' data:;
```

Comment: Under Response Headers for the page

Answer (score 0):

> [font-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/font-src) reference doc from MDN

The Content-Security-Policy header is set by your api. Check your api response for its value.
As per the error, I think your fonts are loaded from a different domain than your application domain. Unless your api whitelists that domain, your browser will not load the font.

Example:

```
Content-Security-Policy: font-src https://example.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

just close all browser, clear cache and restart VSC or your code editor. Ir worked fro me.